# Programatically render a block in a twig template

Tags: blocks, 8

I need to render a views block in my page.html.twig template. In D7 I would do this:

```
<?php
  $block = module_invoke('module_name', 'block_view', 'block_delta');
  print render($block['content']);
?>
```

In Drupal 8 module_invoke is deprecated and recommended to use this: (I've added the block's name as the second parameter)

```
Drupal::moduleHandler()->invoke($block, 'views_block__blog_block_1', $args = array());
```

I tried a few things. First tried to do it in a twig template but I don't know how to call php functions in a twig template, so that didn't turn out too well.

Then I called the function in the preprocess_page() function in the .theme file but before I could get it to work I tried something simpler just to try make a variable work inside the twig template which didn't work either, for example:

In the template_preprocess_page(&$vars) function in the .theme file:

```
$test = 'Hello World';
$vars['$my_var'] = $test;
```

I tried to call my_var inside the twig template but it didn't work and I got an error message saying "The site has an error, please contact the administrator"

So, to summarize, here are my questions:

1. How do I make variables available inside twig templates?
2. How do I call functions inside twig templates?
3. Do I render blocks inside the .theme file or twig template?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You're on the wrong track with module_invoke(). That's just a fancy way of calling the {$module_name}_block_view() function.

The fact that it changed doesn't matter, the point is that the block system completely changed in 8.x and is now using plugins and config entities, those functions no longer exist.

You have a few options.

a) Re-use an existing block config entity and view it. Very easy, but requires that configuration to exist, e.g. as a disabled block.

```
$block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('your_block_id');
$variables['block_output'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getViewBuilder('block')
  ->view($block);
```

b) Create the block plugin instance directly, pass it the configuration (you can find the block plugin id and configuration easily in an exported block config entity). The downside is that you don't get render caching, but if you display it somewhere that is already cached (like a node template), that doesn't really matter.

```
$variables['block_output'] = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block')
  ->createInstance($plugin, $configuration)
  ->build();
```

c) In case of a view, you can also load the view directly and display it.

d) You can also re-think your approach completely and use block regions or [Page Manager](http://drupal.org/project/page_manager) (which uses standard block plugins in 8.x).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to go with A or B. A Region will work but I want to avoid using a region. The only problem I'm having is when I call block_output in the twig template I have an error - "Unexpected tag name "block_output" so I don't know how to make that variable available even though I created it in the preprocess_page function. I will try work it out.

Comment: Sounds like you're using {% ? Use {{ block_output }}.

Comment: Yes, that was it! Still trying to get the hang of twig. Thanks.

Comment: Since Drupal 8.0.0 _entityManager_ is deprecated. Use _entityTypeManager_ instead.

Comment: where do I put this code? $block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('your_block_id'); $variables['block_output'] = \Drupal::entityManager() ->getViewBuilder('block') ->view($block); Thank you!

Comment: @Mustafa Alshamaa You can put that code inside `hook_preprocess_page` function in your themename.theme file OR just write it in your custom module.

Comment: Page Manager link seems dead.

Comment: "you can find the block plugin id and configuration easily in an exported block config entity" hey, glad this is "easily" done, can you give an example of doing this programmatically?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Just create a block that's configured the way you want to do it, then export the configuration and check the plugin ID and configuration in there. Then embed that into your code.

Comment: Using the b) option looks like is not taking into account the block.html.twig markup do you have an idea @berdir?

Comment: @Berdir the big problem I had with option a) was invalidating the cache when the block content changes. I had to do some potentially expensive things to find the original entities' ID so that I could add a cache tag like 'block_content:1' where 1 is the ID of the block as stored in the block_content table. Is there an easier way of setting this cache tag?

Comment: Option a) results in a fatal error...  Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\\block\\BlockViewBuilder::view() must implement interface Drupal\\Core\\Entity\\EntityInterface, null given

Comment: What is "your_block_id"?  Is that an integer or a string?  Where do I get my block's ID?

Answer (score 13):

In Drupal 8, this works for rendering a block plugin (that is, one that you've created in a custom module) in a preprocess_hook:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_something(array &$variables) {
  $customblock = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block')->createInstance('my_custom_block', []);
  $variables['content']['custom_block_output'] = $customblock->build();
}
```

You can then render it in your twig template like this:

```
{{ content.custom_block_output }}
```

Note: this will load up a generic version of your block.  If you want to load up an instance of your block with variables (after you have created it at /admin/structure/block), you have to load it this way:

```
    // Load Instance of custom block with variables
    $example_block = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('block')->load('example_block_machine_name');
    if (!empty($example_block)){
      $example_block_content = \Drupal::entityManager()
        ->getViewBuilder('block')
        ->view($example_block);
      if ($example_block_content) {
        // Add block content to build array
        $variables['content']['custom_block_output'] = $example_block_content;
      }
    }
```

Comment: This was the solution for me and by far the easiest one.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [*Twig tweak* module](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) for that, then you can use the following syntax:

```
  <dd>{{ drupal_block('myblock') }}</dd>
```

Related: [How do I programmatically place a block?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/197013/1908)