# Block Regions in node.html.twig

Tags: blocks, 8, theming

How can i use block regions in my node.html.twig in drupal 8 ?

i tried this :

```
block_get_blocks_by_region
```

but function not found

Comment: Try \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('block')->loadByProperties(['region' => $region, 'theme' => \Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme()->getName()]);

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/153184/programatically-render-a-block-in-a-twig-template/153195#153195

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by adding this function to my theme

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

$block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('views_block__sidebar_meetings_group_page');
$variables['block_output'] = \Drupal::entityManager()
  ->getViewBuilder('block')
  ->view($block);

}
```

thanks @ivan jaros and @berdir