# How to render a facet block?

Tags: 8, blocks, search

I've created a facet block according to this example [Programatically render a block in a twig template](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/153184/programatically-render-a-block-in-a-twig-template?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I've created the facet block as follows:

```
$variables['block_output'] = Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block')->createInstance("facet_block:topic")->build();
```

That works great, but I'm missing the block template itself on my page (the block around the facet links output). I need a custom suggestion for this block to format it. Unfortunately, the hook_theme_suggestions_alter() doesn't detect this block. How can I add a file name suggestion?

Thank you!

Comment: try \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBilder('block')->view($block, $view_mode). Also you need the block entity, not plugin. Block entity basically bundles the plugin and configuration for it together. Discard previous, just entity_load('block', $id)->view($view_mode) should work.

Comment: Yes, that works, assuming that you *have* a block. See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/153184/programatically-render-a-block-in-a-twig-template?lq=1. build of the plugin just contains the content of the block. Page manager uses block plugins too and has its own templates. You could build a structure similar to what BlockViewBuilder does or you could simply add your markup around it yourself in your template.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Berdir, what do you mean with "build a structure similar to what BlockViewBuilder does" exactly? Can you make a example? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

I'm using the module [**Twig Tweak**](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak), so you don't have to create a block, but you can add in in your twig file.

In my `views-view--view-id--page.html.twig` file I use it like this:

```
<div>
 {{ drupal_block('facet_block:facet_id') }}
</div>
```

Where the facet_id is the machine name of my facet.