# How do I add a custom block to a view?

Tags: 8, blocks

In preset views like the *Taxonomy Term* one (/taxonomy/term/%), it can be done by adding a custom block to the footer, but it is not controllable as block layout on /admin/structure/block.

Is it possible to add a region to a custom view template?

Comment: One way to do it is a create a node page and add the view display block and other blocks to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply go to `/admin/structure/block` and add the block to a region.

In configure block, under Visibility, click on pages tab and type path with wildcard `/taxonomy/term/*`.

Therefore, this block will only be visible in your taxonomy page view.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I very rarely output views as pages because of their initial limitations. If you output the view as a block, you can simply plug it in, using the `/admin/structure/block` interface. You could also try out the [Panels module](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) instead of using the blocks interface. It has an intuitive interface, which makes arranging layouts easy. If you're unfamiliar with Panels, here's a [basic tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mEYdtxP46BU) on how to get started.

If you're comfortable editing templates, you can plug in a block using [the instructions given in this top answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/153184/programatically-render-a-block-in-a-twig-template). Here's a little more [information on customizing Views templates](http://redcrackle.com/blog/drupal-8/theme-views-templates).