# How do I place a block in a region, programatically?

Tags: blocks, theming

Why isn't my custom block rendering in the region I want? It shows in the *content* region, not my custom *content_right* region.

```
function bootstrap_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'some.path') {
    $block = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('block_content')->load(12);
//kint($block);
    $block_view = \Drupal::entityManager()->getViewBuilder('block_content')->view($block);
    $variables['page']['content_right']['custom_block'] = $block_view;
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, create an instance of a block plugin on the fly for the block content:

```
$block_content = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('block_content')->load(12);

$plugin_id = 'block_content:' . $block_content->uuid();
$block_view = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block')
  ->createInstance($plugin_id, [])
  ->build();

$variables['page']['content_right']['custom_block'] = $block_view;
```

But it's better to configure the block plugin in UI and build the configured block instead. For more info see this question [Programatically render a block in a twig template](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/153184/programatically-render-a-block-in-a-twig-template)