# Fetching and rendering custom-library generated blocks in twig

Tags: 8, theming, blocks

I am using the following code in my theme to fetch 3 blocks (each containing 4 fields) generated via the custom block library interface i:e all 3  block are of the HomePage-Block type:

```
function legislation_research_theme_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
    for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
        $block_entity = Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load($i);// BLOCK_ID
        $block_view[$i] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('block_content')->view($block_entity);
    }

    if ($block_view) {
        $variables['page']['my_block'] = $block_view;
    }
}
```

In my *page--front.html.twig*, my blocks output via:

```
    {{ page.my_block }}
```

However, the output is of the individual fields from each of the blocks rather than 3 divs containing 4 fields of content from each block. That's making it impossible to to style:

[image]

Can anyone advice how I might be able to output each block but contained in individual parent divs?

Comment: A block content entity doesn't have a template on its own. You need to wrap it in a block plugin template, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/236854/how-do-i-place-a-block-in-a-region-programatically

Answer (score 0):

I render my custom library blocks like this:

```
{{drupal_entity('block', 'block_id')}}
```

So you have to search your block at your library and use this block's machine name where i say block_id.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for you response. I just tried it and Twig does not recognise the drupal_entity function and so it fails with an Unknown "drupal_entity" function error message. 

Is there something extra you are doing to make that function active in twig?

Comment: I'm sorry, but i also found that in the documentation. https://drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/rendering-blocks-with-twig-tweak

Comment: I see! But that would work only if the Twig Tweak module is installed. I'm assuming you do?

Comment: Yes, i always install this module. I am not so advanced so i thought that was part of the best practice to follow when you install drupal. Something like a starter pack. So my bad.