# Get rendered content of one block created as derivative block

Tags: 8, blocks, plugins

I have created derivative blocks using a method such as [this](http://blog.dev030.com/posts/dynamically-define-blocks-drupal-8-derivatives) and want to get the contents of a specific derivative block.

I can see all the available blocks (even derivative blocks) that have been assigned to a region with

```
 $ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('block')->execute();
```

but can't see unassigned blocks

I have a feeling that I need to use the code from [berdir's answer b)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/153184/programatically-render-a-block-in-a-twig-template)

```
$variables['block_output'] = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block')
   ->createInstance($plugin, $configuration)
   ->build();
```

but don't know what to use for `$plugin` or `$configuration`

any help example will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

It sems this will do the trick:

```
  $blockManager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block');
  //see all available block plugins (even not instantiated)
  $contextRepository = \Drupal::service('context.repository');
  $definitions = $blockManager->getDefinitionsForContexts($contextRepository->getAvailableContexts());
```

Here is how I used this info:

```
function TEMPLATE_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $blockManager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block');   
  $vars['content']['derivative_block'] = $blockManager->createInstance('module_name:block_derivative_id')->build();
}
```

If you enable the commented lines `$definitions` will get you all available blocks

Credit goes out to [enzo](http://enzolutions.com/articles/2015/11/21/how-to-manipulate-an-entityblock-programmatically-in-drupal-8/) for this solution.

More info about [programmatic block placement](https://www.drupal.org/node/26502).