# Content type / block or page .. how do we create a small text for a page in D8

Tags: 8, blocks

Let's say, I have a footer where I want to show a simple text **not** menu or link just a simple block of text. So, since it's neither a page, an article or block ... is there any way to create a text and show it somewhere in D8?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be a block?

Comment: It's a text. I thought block is for something structural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blocks can be used for many things including showing simple texts. Go to `/block/add` and create a block. Here you can provide a description and some body text. After saving your block you are redirected to the block configuration where you can place it.

By placing the block Drupal creates a block instance. For more information please see: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/block/overview

Comment: Is there a way to specifically place a block inside a twig template? Say, in my `footer.html.twig` can I create a div and call that block instead of doing `{{ page.footer }}`

Comment: Yes that's possible, see: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/153184/programatically-render-a-block-in-a-twig-template