# Setting visibility by content type while adding block to region from code

Tags: blocks, 9

I created block from code. Now I want to add it to specific region ('sidebar_first') also from code. I'm doing it like this:

```
function event_block_preprocess_page(&$vars)
{
    if (\Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('event_block_1') == null){
        $values = array(
            // A unique ID for the block instance.
            'id' => 'event_block_1',
            // The plugin block id as defined in the class.
            'plugin' => 'event_block',
            // The machine name of the theme region.
            'region' => 'sidebar_first',
            'settings' => array(
                'label' => 'Event block',
            ),
            // The machine name of the theme.
            'theme' => 'bartik',
            'visibility' => array()
            ),
            'weight' => 100,
        );
        $block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::create($values);
        $block->save();
    }
}
```

This works, but problem is that block is displayed on every page. What I want is to display that block only on pages in content type "event".

When configuring block from back-end there is "visibility" section and inside it there is a tab allowing setting block to be visible only on specific content types. I want to achieve the same from code. I expect that additional parameters should be passed to "visibility" array and I tried something like:

```
    'visibility' => array(
        'node_type' => array(
            'event'
        )
    ),
```

or

```
        'visibility' => array(
            'content_type' => array(
                'event'
            )
        ),
```

but nothing of those works. How can I set visibility by content type?

Comment: Each visibility plugin has different settings. The easiest way to find out is to configure a block in UI and export the config. BTW don't save config when rendering a page, this is very bad for performance. In case of a block you can use config on the fly, see point b) in this great answer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/153195/47547. But I don't know if it makes sense to have visibility conditions in this case when you can check the visibility before you create the block on the fly.

Comment: Thanks @4k4, trick with exporting configuration works well. BTW, I'm saving configuration only once, with first call, if block is not save already. But will check the way you suggested.