# Get the breadcrumb inside my node template

Tags: nodes, 9, breadcrumbs

How can I move my breadcrumb from my **page.html.twig** into my **node--content-type.html.twig** ?

In my page template, I display the breadcrumb like this :

```
<div id="main-wrapper" class="layout-main-wrapper clearfix">
  {% block content %}
    <div id="main">
      {{ page.breadcrumb }}
      <main{{ content_attributes.removeClass('col') }} id="main">
        <section class="section">
          <a id="main-content" tabindex="-1"></a>
          {{ page.content }}
        </section>
      </main>
    </div>
  {% endblock %}
</div>
```

I want to do something like that inside my node template.

EDIT :

I've already tried with Twig Tweak like this

```
{{ drupal_block('system_breadcrumb_block') }}
```

It's showing the breadcrumb inside the node--..html.twig, but it's still rendering in the page.html.twig

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programatically render a block in a twig template](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/153184/programatically-render-a-block-in-a-twig-template) - The easist way is the last answer using Twig Tweak module

Comment: Alternatively, you can install the [Twig Tweak module](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak/) and use their twig function, `drupal_breadcrumb()`. (Or use their `drupal_block()` function as noted in [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/242262/48114)).